# SQL In Clause with Zero to Many Parameters

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a SQL query which is parameterized by a very limited in-house framework. The query looks like this:

```
Select * from somewhere
where name IN (:parameter);
```

The code will inject zero to many strings into the location specified by :parameter. The ":parameter" flag can only be used within the "IN" clause (so it can't be moved after the where clause to conditionally insert the 'name IN') section.

Sometimes the user will set parameter to:

'dog', 'cat'

Other times, the user will not put any values into the :parameter variable. This causes a problem since the resulting SQL query will be:

```
Select * from somewhere
where name IN ();
```

My code can catch the case where parameter is empty, but I need something which I can inject into the IN statement which is guaranteed to NEVER match an actual string.

Is there any SQL regular expression which I could inject which would NEVER match any string? Something like %.% or something....

Thanks!

Comment: This might need some further thought. Assuming the query is your actual query, you are basically selecting every record and every column in a (presumably large, if it requires an IN clause) database table, which may not be the best strategy.

Comment: looking at it from the other direction, why not disallow the user to submit the page if that field is empty?

Comment: @Robert - there are actually other parts in the query; I simplified it for the purposes of stackoverflow; however the other parts do not remove the problem with the name parameter

Comment: @nathan - the third party framework collects the value of the parameter and it does not have a flag for "required" parameter

Comment: @Robert - as an example of a more complete query, it might be something like 'select * from somewhere where city = 'chicago' and startDate > '2010' and eventName IN ()......

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can say:

```
where name in (null)
```

This will never match, since nothing is equal to `null` (not even `null` itself.)

Comment: Good answer, but why `null` does not match `null`?

Comment: @fastcodejava: "comparisons with Null can never result in either True or False, but always in a third logical result, Unknown" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL) So `null = null` results in `unknown`, and the `where` clause only matches on `true`.

Comment: extract(days from ts.triggered_at) IN (null) Not work for me in postgresql

Answer (score 4):

`null` should not match with anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can guarantee that you will never match a existing string. The best thing that you could do is handle the case in which the statement doesn't work on the database; however, without knowing how the script is being executed I can't figure out much more from there.

Answer (score 0):

Name cannot be null, so you can do empty string?