# SQLGrammarException when setting empty set as SQL IN parameter

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

My code causes a [`SQLGrammarException`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/exception/SQLGrammarException.html) when I set an empty set into a SQL IN parameter:

```
Query query = this.entMngr.createNativeQuery("SELECT foo_id, first, last FROM foo WHERE bar IN :barSet");
//barSet is a Set<Integer>
query.setParameter("barSet", barSet);
//this throws exception
List<Object> nativeList =  query.getResultList();
```

Everything works when the set is not empty.  How can I make this agnostic of whether the set (or any collection submitted) is populated or not?

Comment: Logically, the result of your query with an empty set is an empty result set. So I'd just special case `barSet.empty()` to return `Collections.emptyList()`

Comment: @Dathan this can make the code a bit faster, but will add complexity to the code. Here I would prefer a bit more maintainable code (with `barSet.add(null);`) versus a bit more faster code (with checking for special case).

Comment: Sure, I see where you're coming from. But I wasn't concerned with the efficiency when I made my comment; I consider the insertion of unobvious code to accommodate SQL edge cases to be more "complex" and certainly less readable than an explicit check for the edge case with early return. The former is going to require commenting for documentation, while the latter is a very common and well-understood idiom.

Comment: @Dathan explicit check is also going to require comment about why this extra check should not be removed... And what you will do if there are multiple `IN` clauses in a query?..

Comment: @dened I don't think the if statement would require its own comment -- I think it's pretty intuitively obvious. But the multiple `IN` clauses case is a very good point - in that case it's far cleaner to use the `null` trick than any other ways I can think of to handle the case.

Comment: @Dathan and actually the problem here is not multiple `IN` clauses, but rather possibility that some queries return not-empty result even with an "empty" `IN` clause (even if there is only one `IN`). And an extra problem here is that if you change a query causing it to start return non-empty result even with "empty" `IN` clause, then you also should do something with an explicit check, and if you forget to do it, you are in trouble... There are no such problems if you use the `NULL` trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that SQL syntax doesn't allow empty `IN` clause. So in your case, `barSet` should not be empty. But you can simply add `null` to the collection before passing it to the query:

```java
barSet.add(null);
query.setParameter("barSet", barSet);
```

You can read about this trick here: [SQL In Clause with Zero to Many Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709703/sql-in-clause-with-zero-to-many-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

In clause in hibernate works with `Query.setParameterList()` https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameterList(java.lang.String, java.util.Collection) method.

You need to use this method and pass a Collection or an Array as a parameter.

```
Query query = this.entMngr.createNativeQuery("SELECT foo_id, first, last FROM foo WHERE bar IN :barSet");
//barSet is a Set<Integer>
query.setParameterList("barSet", barSet); // as barSet is a Collection.
//this throws exception
List<Object> nativeList =  query.getResultList();
```